# Jenkins with cucumber-html-reports post build

Tags: jenkins, cucumber-jvm

I'm trying to publish Cucumber json report with the [cucumber-html-reports (configuration)](https://github.com/masterthought/jenkins-cucumber-jvm-reports-plugin-java/wiki/Detailed-Configuration) plugin. I have version 0.0.19 installed.

Since my Jenkins' context is **/jenkins-ci/** I need to add the parameter **Plugin Url Path** as described in the page instructions. I try to put **/jenkins-ci/** or full URL: **host:port/jenkins-ci/plugin** but both options fail.

Note - The build passes. Reports are created. The console output is good, but clicking the reports link, I get a 404...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected, the problem was a combination of problems in my generated json file (empty targets) and problems with the plugin.

After some joint work with **Kingsley Hendrickse** (the author of the plugin), a new version of the plugin was released (0.0.20), which fixed all these problems!

The plugin page is [here](http://www.masterthought.net/section/cucumber-reporting).

I want to publicly thank **Kingsley** for his help and support!

I hope somone finds this post useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `http://host:port/jenkins-ci/`. Don't forget the trailing slash.

Comment: I tried. No success. I suspect my problem is not there, but in the json report the maven plugin generates. I'm debugging this these days.

Comment: @EldadAK do you have flash charts disabled? I noticed that I can get the report only with charts on.